# SOS Datetime Timedelta 24 hours

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta

So i have got some multiple data (satellite data) for every hour over two years. They start at 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM and End at 31/12/2020 23:00:00 PM. I want to calculate a new field in ArcGIS in date format. Thats why i need a python script for that. So it should look like that: 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM, 1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM ... 1/1/2019 23:00:00 PM. So for 24 hours over two years. My last date should be 31/12/2020 23:00:00 PM. Does that help?

Any proposals?

Thanks forward!

Greetings,
Andrea

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: can you add desired input output to be more clear?

Comment: import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
print(a.time())
print(b.time())

Comment: But I dont know what is the expression and what is belonging to the code block :/ sorry I am a absolute python beginner especially in ArcGIS..

Comment: For example what are your expected input/output?

Comment: my desired input should be like that: Start: 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM, 1/1/2019 01:00:00 AM up to 24 hours till the next day starts, End: 31/12/2020 23:00:00 PM, I need it for my timeslider thats why it has to be in that format.

Comment: please edit your question to be  more clear with input/output

Comment: So i have got some multiple data (satellite data)  for every hour over two years. They start at 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM and End at 31/12/2020 23:00:00 PM. I want to calculate a new field in ArcGIS in date format. Thats why i need a python script for that. So it should look like that: 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM, 1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM ... 1/1/2019 23:00:00 PM. So for 24 hours over two years. My last date should be 31/12/2020 23:00:00 PM. Does that help?

Comment: i know your new , but please edit your question to be more clearly explain your desired input /oupt  by step
otherwise i can't help you

Comment: Yep sorry I am new...but that does that help?

Comment: Sorry but I am confused did you get my comment?

Comment: so you want to increase 1 hour from the start date until the end date? for each time

Comment: Yep total correct...in that format 1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM etc.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm  ... please have a look at the link, there is an expression box and a code block...i dont know where to write the syntax...

Comment: the answer is good for you?

Comment: It looks very good !!! Thank you so much Beny :)...just only two little things...what belongs to the expression box and what to the code block? :/ and the End date is 1/31/2020 23:00:00 PM

Comment: it's was example you can edit the code

Comment: Ok and can I write it in the code block or expression block?

Comment: Can I upload some picture somewhere? there is a little error :/

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like that

```
#!/user/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Iterator

from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, HOURLY


def between_date(start_date: str, end_date: str, freq: int = DAILY) -> Iterator[datetime.date]:
    """
    generate dates form start_date and end_date
    :param start_date: start period.
    :param end_date: end period.
    :return: iterator of dates.
    :param freq: DAILY, MONTH etc..
    """
    date_template = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
    for df in rrule(freq=freq, dtstart=datetime.strptime(start_date, date_template),
                    until=datetime.strptime(end_date, date_template)):
        yield df.strftime(date_template)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_date = "1/1/2019 00:00:00 AM"
    end_date = "1/1/2019 23:00:00 PM"
    for d in between_date(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, freq=HOURLY):
        print(d)
```

output

```
01/01/2019 00:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 01:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 02:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 03:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 04:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 05:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 06:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 07:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 08:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 09:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 10:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 11:00:00 AM
01/01/2019 12:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 13:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 14:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 15:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 16:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 17:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 18:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 19:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 20:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 21:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 22:00:00 PM
01/01/2019 23:00:00 PM
```